# Dropwizard 1.0 Integration Testing: Hitting an external API

Tags: java, api, unit-testing, integration, dropwizard

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate an external API and run every integration test against it. I've been reading and looking at:

- https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/test/java/com/example/helloworld/IntegrationTest.java
- https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/manual/testing.rst

but it looks like these are examples of testing local endpoints and not external ones. I would like to be able to test my api calls with JUnit tests. Currently I'm having to start up and run my app to make sure they're working.

This is the direction I'm currently exploring:

```
private Client client;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    client.close();
}

@Test
public void testHitApi() throws Exception {
    client.target("https://api.github.com/users/" + getUser() + "/repos");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi, do I understand that correctly - you want tot test a resource that you have built? You should read: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html It describes how to spin up a unit test with your resource that you can then hit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the api call to hit the endpoint.

doing just :

```
client.target("https://api.github.com/users/" + getUser() + "/repos")
```

returns a WebTarget .

you should ideally do something like:

```
client
.target("https://api.github.com/users/" + getUser() + "/repos")
.request()
.get() ;   //  for a get call
```

google for exact post/put/delete calls .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to run your integration tests against an external api or a separate running instance of your api.

```
  testEnvironment = new Environment("Test environment", Jackson.newObjectMapper(),
            null, new MetricRegistry(), null);

ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    IntegrationTestConfiguration integrationTestConfiguration = mapper.readValue(fixture("integration-testing-config.yml"),
            IntegrationTestConfiguration.class);
```

Instantiate your client as so

```
 exampleClient = new exampleClient(testEnvironment,    clientConfiguration);
```

Hope this helps.